# Placing Custom Images Instead of Default Google Map Markers

Tags: google-maps

This is probably a silly question, but I am having a hard time finding good resources for this just by googling.

I have 3 different markers that I'd simply like to look different.  Is there a good and simple tutorial for this?  or could someone just paste some code to do that?  I imagine its a one-liner kind of thing.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your [Marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker), set the `icon` and `shadow` properties of the [MarkerOptions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions) to the images of your choice. There are lots of [examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html), [this one](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple.html) might get you started.